# Identify editor

Tags: php, editor, footer

In a lot of PHP scripts I see following in the footer:

```
/* End of file xyz.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/xyz.php */
```

I believe that is autogenerated by editor. Can someone identify that editor?

Thanks

Comment: I'd imagine a fairly large number of editors have that...and who's to say it's autogenerated?

Answer (score 0):

It can either b auto or be manual. Also it may vary editor to editor. Is one editor places its name in the starting of the code then an coder can either keep that or also can remove that.